# Can an ability enhancer be passed down to your children?

Tags: super-powers, genetics

If a person with an ability gains an ability enhancer and has children with their own abilities, would those children be more powerful/ have more range than a child born before their parent gained the enhancer? In short are ability enhancers hereditary?

Comment: Ability enhancers are fictional. You get to decide what the rules are. They can be hereditary if you wish. Just try to be consistent with your rules, to avoid confusing people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that super-powers are totally fictional, also how they propagate to the progenie are equally fictional; in other words:"it's up to you, the author".

Have you read/seen stories about zombie?

In some the zombies are slow, dumb creatures seeking just for a human to bite. In others the zombies are clever and agile creatures which are way more challenging to avoid. That's because, being fictional creatures, they obey to what their author deems more suited for the purpose of the story.

You do the same.